# Postgresql - How to improve low cache hit ratio

Tags: postgresql

If the cache hit ratio for a database is below 50%. Are there other ways than increasing the shared_buffers to improve this ratio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your explain plans. `Hit` and `Read` are cache and disk reads respectively. There can be a number of reasons for this the most common being lack of indexes, or bloated indexes. Poorly vacuumed/analyzed tables which have a lot of dead rows misleading the optimiser.

Look at the pg_stat_statements view. This will show you the blocks hit and read for the most common statements that are executed. You can use this information to determine appropriate index usage.

Good management of your tables and queries will help lower your read over hit rate.

Answer (score 2):

Hit ratio is calculated with formula:

[image: hits/(hits+reads)]

In order to increase ratio the obvious first action is to increase **shared_buffers** (see. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/runtime-config-resource.html)in order to increase postgre cache.

A good value for this parameter is **25% of total amount of memory**.

So if you have a total memory of 16GB, you can set shared_buffers to 4GB.

Now, if you have already done that and hit ratio is still relatively low, this probably means that **the size of your tables in disk are much bigger than your total amount of memory**.

If this is the case adding more RAM to the server will significantly
increase hits & performance.

More RAM => more cache => more hits => higher hit ratio.

Remember you can prepend below code in your queries for more insights regarding execution plans and cache / disk access during sort/merge/agg.

```
explain (analyze on, buffers on, verbose on)
```

Happy tuning ;-)

Answer (score 1):

see: [Re: Increased shared_buffer setting = lower hit ratio ?](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/5465402F.9030509%40fuzzy.cz)

> what exactly do you mean by hit ratio - is that the page cache hit
> ratio (filesystem cache), or shared buffers hit ratio (measured e.g.
> using pg_buffercache)?
>
> Regarding the unexpected decrease of performance after increasing
> shared_buffers - that's actually quite common behavior. First, the
> management of shared buffers is not free, and the more pieces you need
> to manage the more expensive it is. Also, by using larger shared
> buffers you make that memory unusable for page cache etc. There are
> also other negative consequences - double buffering, accumulating more
> changes for a checkpoint etc.
>
> The common wisdom (which some claim to be obsolete) is not to set
> shared buffers over ~10GB of RAM. It's however very workload-dependent
> so your mileage may vary.
>
> To get some basic idea of the shared_buffers utilization, it's
> possible to compute stats using pg_buffercache. Also pg_stat_bgwriter
> contains useful data.
>
> BTW, it's difficult to say why a query is slow - can you post explain
> analyze of the query with both shared_buffers settings?
>
> And just to check - what kind of hardware/kernel version is this? Do
> you have numa / transparent huge pages or similar trouble-indicing
> issues?

- So why do you want to increase cache hit ratio ?
- What do you think is a good ratio?

Comment: I mean the shared buffers hit ratio. I want to get at least 90% cache hit ratio for all databases.